# Disabling certain OpenSSH keys on OpenBSD: why the corresponding 'sshd_config' entries are ignored and why 'ssh-keygen -A' generates forbidden keys?

Tags: ssh, security, ssh-keys, openbsd, ssh-keygen

I am trying to achieve the followings on my OpenBSD 6.9 servers:

1. Forbidding the use of all keys but the `ssh-ed25519` one on both *SERVER* and *CLIENT* sides.
2. Limiting `ssh-keygen -A` to generate keys only by the authorised `ssh-ed25519` algorithm and nothing else.

In order to achieve these, I have added the following lines to my `sshd_config`:

```
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
CASignatureAlgorithms ssh-ed25519
HostbasedAcceptedKeyTypes ssh-ed25519
HostKeyAlgorithms ssh-ed25519
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes ssh-ed25519
```

I have also added the following lines to my `ssh_config`:

```
CASignatureAlgorithms ssh-ed25519
HostbasedAcceptedKeyTypes ssh-ed25519
HostKeyAlgorithms ssh-ed25519
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes ssh-ed25519
```

I have deleted all keys but the authorised one.

Restarted sshd:

```
# rcctl restart sshd                                                                            
sshd(ok)
sshd(ok)
```

After verifying whether my settings are utilised by running the following commands:

```
# ssh -Q HostbasedAcceptedAlgorithms
# ssh -Q HostKeyAlgorithms
# ssh -Q PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms
```

For my surprise, this is what they all return with:

```
ssh-ed25519
ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com
sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com
sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com
ssh-rsa
rsa-sha2-256
rsa-sha2-512
ssh-dss
ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
ecdsa-sha2-nistp384
ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com
webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com
ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com
rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com
rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com
ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com
ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com
ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com
ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com
sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com
```

In other words, the key restrictions are ignored.

Just to be on the safe side, I have even restarted the server, but there is no difference.

A potential workaround is to remove all key files but the authorised one. However, the init script `/etc/rc` has a line, `ssh-keygen -A`, which regenerates all missing ssh keys after every system reboot, before the sshd daemon would start, **including those of forbidden algorithms**!

So removing the keys does not solve the problem.

As an additional workaround, I could remove the `ssh-keygen -A` line from the init script or replace it with my custom key generation algorithm, but that will lead back to where it has all started: having to deal with this problem over and over again, e.g. after every system update, whenever the OpenBSD team releases a new version of `/etc/rc`. Automating the removal of that line and testing such a sloppy workaround on large number of servers is difficult and it can lead to a massive network failure if something goes wrong.

Therefore, I continued my investigation and I dug into the source code of `ssh-keygen`. I have found out that it is not possible to restrict the behaviour of the `-A` switch from outside e.g. via config files. It does not even perform a preliminary test whether the keys are authorised or not, it just generates the keys, according to a list of algorithms from a hardcoded array. The only way of avoiding this is by editing, recompiling and using a custom fork of `ssh-keygen`, but then I will have to deal with it after every OpenSSH update...

I have found a partial solution for other operating systems but not for OpenBSD.

Could somebody please point me to a proper solution? Why my `sshd_config` and `ssh_config` key restrictions are ignored and how to get `ssh-keygen -A` stop generating keys with forbidden algorithms?

Before anyone would ask: all other settings are utilised in both config files by OpenSSH, so these config files are indeed the actual ones being loaded.

Many thanks for all useful answers.

Comment: For ssh-keygen you should be talking to the OpenSSH developers via whatever issue tracking system they use.

Comment: In addition I'd also complain to the OpenBSD maintainers about their use of ssh-keygen -A in the startup scripts. On Linux the keys are all generated separately and generating each one (e.g. rsa, ecdsa, ed25519) can be enabled or disabled at will independently of the others.